# Getting error: Use of undefined constant num - assumed 'num'

Tags: php

I'm following a php pagination [tutorial](http://papermashup.com/easy-php-pagination/) that uses MYSQL but I use MYSQLI object oriented all around my site. This is causing some errors..

For this part..

```
$sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) as num FROM categories";
$total_pages = $connection->query($sql) or die(mysqli_error($connection)); 
$total_pages = $total_pages['num'];
```

I get *Fatal error: Cannot use object of type mysqli_result as array*.. on the last line

so I switched it to

```
$sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) as num FROM categories";
$total_pages = $connection->query($sql) or die(mysqli_error($connection)); 
$row = $total_pages->fetch_assoc();
$total_pages  = $row[num];
```

and now I get *Use of undefined constant num - assumed 'num'* ..on the last line.

At this point, I'm not sure what else to do. Can someone please help?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

change

```
$total_pages  = $row[num];
```

to:

```
$total_pages  = $row['num'];
```

you were mssing the quotes. Also, notice that the "undefined constant" error is just a **notice**, which means your program should still work but that you should fix it. Always use quotes around strings!

Comment: Mate, thanks for pointing that out! Yes, I noticed that it worked, which I found wierd.

Comment: see "Why is $foo[bar] wrong?" at http://docs.php.net/language.types.array#language.types.array.foo-bar

Answer (score 0):

$row['num'];

Single quotes