# How to show array from show table schema query in php

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, database-schema

i have a query

```
$qdrop=mysqli_query($connect,"select TABLE_NAME,create_time
      FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES 
      WHERE table_schema = 'purbalingga' 
      AND CREATE_TIME <='2016-10-07' and TABLE_NAME LIKE '2016%'");
```

and  a while for show the array

```
while ($datadrop=mysqli_fetch_array($qdrop)) {
      echo $qdrop['TABLE_NAME'];echo"<br/>";
       }
```

But i got an error:

```
Fatal error: Cannot use object of type mysqli_result as array in E:\xampp\htdocs
```

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3379410/getting-error-cannot-use-object-of-type-mysqli-result-as-array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace:

```
while ($datadrop=mysqli_fetch_array($qdrop)) {
  echo $qdrop['TABLE_NAME'];
  echo"<br/>";
}
```

With:

```
while ($datadrop=mysqli_fetch_array($qdrop)) {
  echo $datadrop['TABLE_NAME'];
  echo"<br/>";
}
```

`$qdrop` only holds the query but `$datadrop` is the one holding the `result in array`.